# A real function sending bounded sets to bounded sets is necessarily of bounded variation?

Tags: real-analysis

A real function sending bounded sets to bounded sets is necessarily  of bounded variation?

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(n^4 x)}{n^2}$$ is a bounded continuous function with unbounded variation, too.

Answer (score 2):

No. Take$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}\end{array}$$maps *any* set into a bounded set, but is not of bounded variation.

Comment: You are completely right! Do You know more about these functions?